# VM Keeps restarting

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a VM host in Azure, created using Resource Manager. I've come to use it today and can't RDP to the machine. When I view the Boot Diagnostics it has Please Wait. after a period of time it will go to the logon screen. When I view the CPU usage you can see it drop which assume is the VM restarting.

I've tried the following :

- Reset Password
- Reset Configuration
- Redeploy

I've also looked at the network interfaces and tried adding it to a network security group with RDP rule but still nothing.

Is there anything else I can check?

**EDIT**
When I first start the VM up and look at the Boot diagnostics I can see the login screen. When I try and RDP to the machine it says it can't connect.
The CPU drops where I assume its restarting, I've tried RDP to the machine from another machine on the same VPN
[image: Drop in CPU]

[image]

Comment: How are you trying to login?

Comment: @SA Remote Desktop, I cane into one scenario where I logged in and it immediately restarted again and I couldn't logon

Comment: @Boomerang Do you check `Resource Health` on Azure Portal? If possible, you could try to login your VM by using another VM in the same VNet.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT I've updated my question with more. Today it has nothing in the resource health, but attached screen shot for yesterday. The same happens when I RDP from another machine on the same VPN

Comment: @Boomerang Do you check `Boot diagnostics`? If possible, maybe you could delete you vm but keep the VM's VHD. You could recreate you VM by using the VHD. You could use the [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd-existing-vnet) to recrate your VM.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT This VM has AD so a bit dubious and I'm not an expert in this area , would the Redeploy not do the same as you have mentioned ?

Comment: @Boomerang Sorry for my mistake, they are same. You could try resize your VM to a larger size to eliminate the cause of insufficient performance.

Comment: @walter-MSFT I could give that a try, just can't understand why this has suddenly happened. This was part of the 'SharePoint 2013 HA Farm' in azure. If its a trial version would this occur, I know the SharePoint 2013 server restarts after a given amount of time. (as far as I'm aware this does not happen for the SQL server which is part of this template)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135159/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-boomerang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a ticket regarding the following. Support noticed the following in the logs "Rebooting VM to apply DSC configuration." The "DSC extension" was causing the machine to reboot.

They advised me to go to VM in the control panel and then extensions and uninstall the Powershell extension. Not sure what caused this ie I did not knowingly install this. But once I uninstalled it I was able to RDP. Support have asked me to try and install it again and see if the same happens again but at the moment not had a chance to do this.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the root cause.

Comment: Thanks for your share. It is very useful.